# WebBrowser - Modal('Show') and Javascript

Tags: c#, vb.net, modal-dialog

I'm using a standard WebBrowser control to perform various automated web requests. I am aware of the default IE 7 setting unless changed by registry, which I have done, and now use a mainly functional version of IE 10 embedded within my program.

Unfortunately, there are times when I need to click JS buttons to add data to the displayed webpage, and other times when there are Modal popups that require me to input information. Webbrowser chokes on this, and for the button, and popup, does nothing.

I am aware of the route of using ScriptInvoke to send my data, but I wondered if there is any way I can avoid this and just use the WebBrowser control as if it where a normal browser, that accepts the two described functions.

Thanks to all,
Stan.